# Need an array traversal and get a custom output - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, traversal

I have this array which describes dependencies via "preId":

```
 [
    {
        "preId": "Primary Flow",
        "roomRunId": "A1"
    },
    {
        "preId": "A1",
        "roomRunId": "A2"
    },
    {
        "preId": "A2",
        "roomRunId": "B1"
    },
    {
        "preId": "B1",
        "roomRunId": "B2"
    },
    {
        "preId": "D2",
        "roomRunId": "C1"
    },
    {
        "preId": "C1",
        "roomRunId": "C2"
    },
    {
        "preId": "C2",
        "roomRunId": "C3"
    },
    {
        "preId": "A2",
        "roomRunId": "D1"
    },
    {
        "preId": "D1",
        "roomRunId": "D2"
    },
    {
        "preId": "D2",
        "roomRunId": "E1"
    },
    {
        "preId": "E1",
        "roomRunId": "E2"
    }
]
```

The output that I need, consists of all possible paths from the "Primary Flow" node up to any end-point (with no successors):

```
array[0] = ['Primany Flow', A1, A2, B1, B2]
array[1] = ['Primany Flow', A1, A2, D1, D2, C1, C2]
array[2] = ['Primany Flow', A1, A2, D1, D2, E1, E2]
```

The following flow diagram can help:

[image]

I have tried 2 methods both did not work well for me:

```js
let predecessorArray = [{
    "preId": "Primary Flow",
    "roomRunId": "A1",
    "massFlowRate": 0,
    "totPressureLoss": 0,
    "roomName": "Hall",
    "radName": ""
  },
  {
    "preId": "A1",
    "roomRunId": "A2",
    "massFlowRate": 0.025057471264367817,
    "totPressureLoss": 0.3140373889332768,
    "roomName": "Hall",
    "radName": "K2"
  },
  {
    "preId": "A2",
    "roomRunId": "B1",
    "massFlowRate": 0,
    "totPressureLoss": 0,
    "roomName": "Bathroom 1",
    "radName": ""
  },
  {
    "preId": "B1",
    "roomRunId": "B2",
    "massFlowRate": 0.003090676883780332,
    "totPressureLoss": 0.010366737225913495,
    "roomName": "Bathroom 1",
    "radName": "P1"
  },
  {
    "preId": "D2",
    "roomRunId": "C1",
    "massFlowRate": 0,
    "totPressureLoss": 0,
    "roomName": "Lounge",
    "radName": ""
  },
  {
    "preId": "C1",
    "roomRunId": "C2",
    "massFlowRate": 0.007407407407407407,
    "totPressureLoss": 1.1403139132429296,
    "roomName": "Lounge",
    "radName": "P+"
  },
  {
    "preId": "C2",
    "roomRunId": "C3",
    "massFlowRate": 0.007765006385696041,
    "totPressureLoss": 2.8476786818485933,
    "roomName": "Lounge",
    "radName": "K2"
  },
  {
    "preId": "A2",
    "roomRunId": "D1",
    "massFlowRate": 0,
    "totPressureLoss": 0,
    "roomName": "Kitchen",
    "radName": ""
  },
  {
    "preId": "D1",
    "roomRunId": "D2",
    "massFlowRate": 0.012720306513409963,
    "totPressureLoss": 3.893907699404828,
    "roomName": "Kitchen",
    "radName": "K1"
  },
  {
    "preId": "D2",
    "roomRunId": "E1",
    "massFlowRate": 0,
    "totPressureLoss": 0,
    "roomName": "Bedroom 1",
    "radName": ""
  },
  {
    "preId": "E1",
    "roomRunId": "E2",
    "massFlowRate": 0.004223073648361005,
    "totPressureLoss": 0.007077131909800973,
    "roomName": "Bedroom 1",
    "radName": "P1"
  }
]

let teesOn = false;
let addToNewArray;
let teaNo = 0
let teaNo1;
let indexTableDataInit = {}

indexTableDataInit[teaNo] = !indexTableDataInit[teaNo] ? [] : indexTableDataInit[teaNo];

for (let L = 0; L < predecessorArray.length; L++) {
  let indexTableDataObj = {
    runId: '',
    totPressureLoss: 0
  }

  let foundRow = predecessorArray.filter(function(o, i) {
    if (o) {
      if (o.preId == predecessorArray[L].preId) {
        return o;
      }
    }
  })

  if (predecessorArray[L]) {
    indexTableDataObj.runId = predecessorArray[L].roomRunId;
    indexTableDataObj.totPressureLoss = predecessorArray[L].totPressureLoss;
  }

  if (foundRow.length == 0) {
    //end of tree
    indexTableDataInit[teaNo].push(indexTableDataObj)
    teaNo = teaNo + 1
  }
  if (foundRow.length == 1) {
    //add to single array
    indexTableDataInit[teaNo] = !indexTableDataInit[teaNo] ? [] : indexTableDataInit[teaNo];
    indexTableDataInit[teaNo].push(indexTableDataObj)
  }
  if (foundRow.length == 2) {
    //its a tea/node
    //adding to double array
    indexTableDataInit[teaNo] = !indexTableDataInit[teaNo] ? [] : indexTableDataInit[teaNo];
    teaNo1 = teaNo + 1;
    indexTableDataInit[teaNo].push(indexTableDataObj)
    if (!indexTableDataInit[teaNo1]) {
      let a = indexTableDataInit[teaNo];
      addToNewArray = [];
      a.forEach(function(k) {
        addToNewArray.push(k)
      });
      indexTableDataInit[teaNo1] = addToNewArray
    }
  }
}

console.log(indexTableDataInit)
```

I have tried it with the above code, but I was not able to bring the total output I was looking for: it produces 2 paths (3 are expected), and the first "path" has all the nodes, including invalid sequences, like B2 (an endpoint) followed by C1.

Comment: _"I prefer not to share the code, the better part is I am looking for a solution for this"_ - That's not how SO works. We help with actual problems.

Comment: Without *"your"* code there is nothing to debug. Check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info

Comment: @Andreas - I do know how SO works, but my code has a lot of other un-necessary stuffs. Still I have pasted the one I tried lastly with. See if it is useful in any way.

Comment: _"but my code has a lot of other un-necessary stuffs."_ - Then it's not a [mcve]

Comment: What is the rule for the expected output (_"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text"_)? Are there other options than `A` to `E`?

Comment: @Andreas, about not posting images: This isn't an image with code... It is visualising the tree that has been given before in text format (JSON). Nothing wrong with that image.

Comment: @trincot _"Please reserve the use of images for ... things that are impossible to describe accurately via text"_ - I don't see an explanation for the output in written form. Without the rules how the output is generated any answer is just a guess based on an image...

Comment: I think it there is not much room for guessing. @AbilashArjunan, I edited your question with a bit more explicit text on which paths are to be output. Please double check if this understanding is indeed what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Build an adjacency list for this graph, converting child-to-parent links to parent-to-child collections. I would suggest using a `Map` for this, where its keys are the node identifiers ("roomRunId"), and the corresponding values are the identifiers of any children (i.e. successors).
- Use a depth-first traversal from the root to find all the leaves (end-points), collecting the path along the way, and yield that path whenever a leaf is reached.

Here is how that could be implemented:

```js
function * dfs(adj, node, path=[node]) {
    if (!adj.get(node).length) yield [...path];
    for (let child of adj.get(node)) {
        yield * dfs(adj, child, path.concat(child));
    }
}

// Sample input
let data = [ { "preId": "Primary Flow", "roomRunId": "A1" }, { "preId": "A1", "roomRunId": "A2" }, { "preId": "A2", "roomRunId": "B1" }, { "preId": "B1", "roomRunId": "B2" }, { "preId": "D2", "roomRunId": "C1" }, { "preId": "C1", "roomRunId": "C2" }, { "preId": "C2", "roomRunId": "C3" }, { "preId": "A2", "roomRunId": "D1" }, { "preId": "D1", "roomRunId": "D2" }, { "preId": "D2", "roomRunId": "E1" }, { "preId": "E1", "roomRunId": "E2" } ];

// Prepare empty adjacency list
let adj = new Map(data.map(o => [o.roomRunId, []])).set("Primary Flow", []);
// Fill adjacency list
for (let o of data) adj.get(o.preId).push(o.roomRunId);
// Collect the paths from root to leaf
console.log([...dfs(adj, "Primary Flow")]);
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I am glad that you understood the problem. This answer is close. We did it in a similar way. Also we used Dijkstra's algorithm to find the longest path.

Comment: Glad that you still came back, after 10 months ;-) Still, I wonder a bit about "This answer is close". Do you mean it is close to what you eventually implemented, or do you mean the answer produces wrong results in some cases...?

Comment: Yes there are a lot of cases in the traversal, that is why I was not able to fully explain it in here. I was trying get help of some algorithm like your reply or the one we found later. Even though this is not the exact answer, I am sure you made a very close call. Sorry I could give you only an up-vote.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but was it the first or the second of what I asked? If it is not an exact answer, what do you mean? Is there something wrong? In that case, I'd really appreciate you would point me to a use case where it goes wrong. I am not interested in votes, BTW.